# como hacer una consulta SQL de diferentes tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wamp, sql

Buen dia espero me puedan ayudar.
Necesito hacer la siguiente consulta: Obtener el nombre completo de los empleados, así como el nombre del departamento, puesto y salario en el que haya laborado.

Tengo la primera consulta que es la siguiente:

SELECT id_emp, id_puesto, id_depto, max(fecha_inicio)as ultimo_puesto
FROM labora
GROUP BY id_emp;

La cual me muestra cuales son los empleados que necesito para posteriormente saber su nombre completo, departamento puesto y salario, pero no se como realizar esa consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Para obtener los datos que necesitas sólo tienes que ir uniendo las tablas (`JOIN`)  por las claves de referencia y agrupando cuando sea necesario.

Empecemos a unir tablas:

```
SELECT
    e.Nombre, 
    e.Paterno, 
    e.Materno,
    d.Nombre Departamento,
    p.Descripcion Puesto,
    c.Salario
FROM
    empleado e
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT Id_Emp, MAX(Fecha_Inicio), Id_Depto, Id_Puesto
      FROM labora GROUP BY Id_Emp, Id_Depto, Id_Puesto
    ) l
      ON e.Id_Emp  = l.Id_Emp

    INNER JOIN departamento d  ON l.Id_Depto = d.Id_Depto 
    INNER JOIN puesto p ON l.Id_Puesto = p.Id_Puesto
    INNER JOIN contiene c ON p.Id_Puesto = c.Id_Puesto AND d.Id_Depto = c.Id_Depto
GROUP BY e.Id_Emp
```

No he probado la consulta, pero debería funcionar.

Aunque yo veo algunos puntos quizá complicados en tu diseño de datos:

- Observarás que he usado una sub-consultar para filtrar por la fecha máxima en la tabla `labora`. No me convence que esa tabla haya sido concebida como una especie de historial donde se van guardando al mismo tiempo las fechas en que un empleado ocupó un puesto y un departamento.
- No sé por qué motivo para saber el salario hay que referirse a dos columnas (parece una concepción algo rígida y muy precaria que devendría infernal cuando ocurra que una persona del mismo departamento y puesto pueda tener un salario diferente de otra).

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida, te agradezco mucho tu comentario. He probado la consulta y tengo una duda. Para realizar la consulta del empleado 1 y 2 en su fecha mas reciente como seria?

Comment: @ArturoOrtizVázquez ya está filtrando por la fecha más reciente, si observas hay entre los `INNER JOIN` una subconsulta donde se selecciona `MAX(Fecha_Inicio)`, no sé si es a eso a lo que te refieres.

Comment: @ArturoOrtizVázquez no entiendo tu duda. Ahí se filtra por la fecha máxima y se agrupa por empleados. Si quieres sólo los datos del empleado 1 y el 2, agregas un `WHERE` al final de la consulta general.

Comment: Perdón no me di ha entender, al momento de hacer la consulta por separado de la fecha máxima me cambia el valor original del Id_Puesto del empleado 1. Originalmente en la fecha 1993-05-30 tiene como valores Id_Emp = 1, Id_Depto = 1 y Id_Puesto = 2 y al realizar por si sola esta consulta                                              
SELECT Id_Emp, MAX(Fecha_Inicio), Id_Depto, Id_Puesto  FROM labora GROUP BY Id_Emp                                                              El valor de Id_ puesto en la fecha 1993-05-30 lo cambia a 3

Comment: Acabo de subir una imagen para que sea mas fácil de entender.

Comment: Entiendo @ArturoOrtizVázquez Pero eso te ocurre con el empleado 1 si haces esta consulta: **`SELECT Id_Emp, MAX(Fecha_Inicio), Id_Depto, Id_Puesto
      FROM labora GROUP BY Id_Emp`**?

Comment: @ArturoOrtizVázquez lo que está ocurriendo aquí confirma mi crítica a tu modelo de datos (al final de la respuesta). Tu tabla `labora` ha sido pensada como una taba *histórica* y como una tabla asociativa al mismo tiempo. Es una tabla además muy importante porque posee dos claves foráneas que sirven de unión a otras dos tablas, pero la condición (en este caso concreto) tiene que pasar además por otro criterio (obtener la fecha máxima entre varias  fechas). Pero, ¿aparte de eso, cómo decirle que tome solamente datos de esa fila y no de cualquier otra como de hecho hace? Es probable que...

Comment: ...haya una forma de hacerlo. Pero aquí creo yo que el problema está en el modelo de datos. La fecha no tiene ningún interés en esa tabla y en mi opinión debería ser relegada a una tabla histórica, manteniendo en el sistema una tabla que exprese la situación actual del empleado: puesto, salario, cargo.  Desde el punto de vista práctico es una tabla que tendrá mucho tráfico (imaginemos una empresa de varios miles de empleados) y no tendría por qué arrastrar con un historial del empleado. Y lo peor de todo son los dolores de cabeza que daría para recuperar las llaves foráneas correctas.

Comment: Ahora entiendo el las observaciones que me hiciste al principio, ni hablar... le comentare  al profesor sobre esto, pero de antemano te agradezco tu respuesta, las observaciones y tu tiempo que me has dado. Me han ayudado mucho a entender la sintaxis para INNER JOIN.

Comment: hola @ArturoOrtizVázquez te sugiero que cuando una respuesta te ayudó a resolver el problema la marques como aceptada

Comment: @shadow Que tal amigo, gracias por tu comentario. No sabia bien la dinámica pero ya la voy entendiendo.

Comment: @ArturoOrtizVázquez cometí un error en la sub-consulta, hay que agregar en el `GROUP BY` las otras columnas: `Id_Depto, Id_Puesto` de lo contrario se estaría violando una regla de funciones agregadas en SQL. A veces el código funciona pero no es recomendable.